# Autorefresh an Excel File At The 45th Second of a Minute

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refresh an excel file at the 45th second of every minute.

Refreshing an excel file every minute can be accomplished using below code; however, I have observed that it drifts by several seconds after every refresh.

```
Sub AutoRefresh()

   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "AutoRefresh"

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help with the code to refresh the excel file at the 45th second of every minute when the workbook is open?

Example:  If I open the workbook at 9:00 AM, I want it to refresh at 9:00:45, again at 9:01:45, 9:02:45, and so on until the Excel file is closed.

thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
Dim nextRun As Date
nextRun = Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now) + 1, 45)
Application.OnTime nextRun, "AutoRefresh"
```

Will work even for minute 59, the `TimeSerial` function can handle minutes (and seconds) >= 60

Answer (score 0):

Just build your exact time with `TimeSerial`

```
Application.OnTime Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now) + IIf(Second(Now) >= 45, 1, 0), 45), "AutoRefresh"
```

This will run in second 45 of the current Minute, and if this is already in the past eg current time is at second 46 then it will run in the next minute at second 45.